# NGINX WebDAV авторизация

Tags: nginx, webdav

Всем привет.
Подскажите как решить задачу.
Есть сервер nginx+webdav, есть папка на сервере /var/data/user1,/var/data/user2 И т.д.
Задача такая при подключении по webdav пользователь указывает логин и пароль, нужно чтоб каждый пользователь попадал в свою папку.
Авторизацию планирую делать через http_auth_request
Как правильно настроить конфиг nginx?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/411962/how-to-map-authenticated-nginx-users-to-their-own-directory

Answer (score 0):

Из общих соображений: как-то сделать так что-бы имя пользователя попало в переменную (думаю `auth_request_set` может в этом помочь), подставить эту переменную в директиву `root` или `alias`

Comment: Возможно сделать таким образом: отправляем запрос на авторизацию, в ответ приход название папки данного пользователя, и подставить в root /var/data/$user_dir ?

Comment: Что-то такое я и имел в виду. Только я имел в виду не имя директории, а имя пользователя (предполагая что они идентичны, или что из одного можно легко сделать другое). Но на сколько я понимаю `http_auth_request` позволяет вернуть nginx-у произвольные значения (через заголовки ответа), так-что без разницы